# Numpy array broadcasting vs explicit dimension expansion space inefficiency

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Why is the explicit dimension expansion so space inefficient as compared to leveraging implicit numpy broadcasting, which technically does the same thing i.e. copies the matrix over on a given dimension.

I have two arrays: X(500,3072) and X_train(5000,3072). I want to calculate distance of all 500 points in X from the 5000 points in X_train. When I try to do this via explicit dimension expansion, it takes over 60GB of space to do this calculation.

```
dists = np.linalg.norm(np.expand_dims(X,axis=1)-(X_train), axis =2)
```

Whereas if I leverage numpy's broadcasting, it gets done within MBs of space.

```
dists = np.square(X).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)+np.square(X_train).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True).T-2*np.dot(X, X_train.T)
```

Why is the explicit dimension expansion so space inefficient despite of such small matrices being used.

Comment: This isn't strictly what you asked, but [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) is usually the fastest way of doing a pairwise distance calculation for all pairs of rows.

Comment: It took me a bit to understand how the second one worked - [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236465/euclidean-distance-and-dot-product) is a helpful resource.

Comment: Technically, both of these are using broadcasting. When it does `np.expand_dims(X,axis=1)-(X_train)`, the subtraction is a broacast. It's also the step where it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking dimensions in the 2 alternatives:

```
X(500,3072) and X_train(5000,3072).  
(500,1,3072) - (1,5000, 30720) => (500,5000,30720)
```

`norm` squares this, and sums on axis 2 (30720) and returns the sqrt.  (500,5000)

That 3d array is quite large, 600GB

```
np.square(X).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)+np.square(X_train).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True).T-2*np.dot(X, X_train.T)

(500,3072)=>(500,1)
(5000,3872)=>(5000,1)==>(1,5000)
==> (500,5000)
dot (500,3072), (3872,5000) ==> (500,5000)
net (500,5000)
```